# In DMARC report other IPs than mine fail check, but disposition is always "none"

Tags: email, spam-prevention, dkim, spf

I have trouble to understand the DMARC reports I receive. In all reports, I get some IPs that are not mine sending a couple of emails, fine, their checks (SPF or DKIM) always fail, but still the disposition is always `none`! While, I specified `reject` 100% of emails failing policy.

Here's the policy I declared, extract from a report I just received :

```
<policy_published>
    <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
    <adkim>s</adkim>
    <aspf>s</aspf>
    <p>reject</p>
    <sp>reject</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
    <fo>0</fo>
</policy_published>
```

And here is a sample of one entry with an IP that is not mine :

```
<record>
    <row>
        <source_ip>11.11.11.11</source_ip>
        <count>1</count>
        <policy_evaluated>
            <disposition>none</disposition>
            <dkim>pass</dkim>
            <spf>fail</spf>
        </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
        <envelope_to>somedomain.com</envelope_to>
        <envelope_from>mydomain.com</envelope_from>
        <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
        <dkim>
            <domain>somedomain2.com</domain>
            <selector>glofish</selector>
            <result>pass</result>
            <human_result>pass</human_result>
        </dkim>
        <dkim>
            <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
            <selector>mail</selector>
            <result>pass</result>
            <human_result>pass</human_result>
        </dkim>
        <spf>
            <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
            <scope>mfrom</scope>
            <result>fail</result>
        </spf>
    </auth_results>
</record>
```

Can someone help me shed light on this? Why is `policy_evaluated`, `disposition` always `none` rather than `reject`?

Comment: Do you have any example with SPF and dkim failing? If I understand correctly, section 6.6.2 of the rfc, step 5, states that if one of them pass, the email is considered to pass dmarc.

Comment: hmm ... no cannot find. Somehow DKIM is always pass.

Comment: Those emails most likely originate from your servers then, they just are being forwarded by severs that do not apply SRS.